# A Strategy for a Number guessing game

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

**Question:** There are two people say, $A$, and $B$ playing a guessing game. $A$ takes a number from the set $\{1,2,3,4,...,40\}$. Then $B$ tries to find the number that $A$ chose. At each turn, $B$ tries to guess the number. Provided that $B$'s guess is correct, $B$ wins the game. Otherwise, $A$ arbitrarily either decreases or increases his/her guess by $1$. Does there exists a strategy guaranteeing that $B$ wins the game in a finite number of turns?

Could you provide any starting point for me to continue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd start by doing it for small $n$ (in the given problem, $n=40$).  For $n=1$ there's nothing to check.  For $n=2$, it is possible to win in finitely many moves (why?).  What about $n=3$?

Comment: If you knew the parity (odd/even) of A's initial number, could you find such a strategy? What if B just assumes for a while that A's initial number was odd, then if that doesn't work "start over" with assuming that A's initial number was even?

Comment: This is a larger version of [Find a bug in under 6 tiles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2580569/find-a-bug-under-6-tiles/). See also [this answer on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29323/math-puzzles-for-dinner/29598#29598).

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you so much, I got it now. The optimal solution would be 2 3 4 5 .... 39 39 38 ..... 2 .