# Algorithm for mouse catching

Tags: logic, algorithms

I have this question that I think  may be interesting to all maths' lovers.

We have $5$ rooms in a row : Room $1$-Room $2$-Room $3$-Room $4$-Room $5$.

There is a little mouse in one of the rooms. А cat tries to catch the mouse and put his leg into one room. If the mouse is in this room then he catches the mouse, otherwise the mouse moves to a nearest room. Тhen the cat again chooses any room etc.

What is the cat's algorithm for catching the mouse?

Comment: This [Finding the Robot](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206095/finding-the-robot) looks like a equivalent question to me, another similar one is [Find a bug under 6 tiles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2580569/find-a-bug-under-6-tiles). – What are *your* thoughts on the problem?

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. you are right

Comment: I have taken the liberty to correct many little grammatical and orthographic details. I am not more than you native English speaker, but you should take care about basics (for example "the cat tries" instead of "try")